# message syntax in sequence diagram

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, sequence-diagram, papyrus

i am using Papyrus for modeling sequence diagram
i wonder if there is syntax that i should follow for the message that resides between lifelines
and also how can identify the variables associated with a message in the parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
<stereotype> methodName(Parameter) : return
```

You might find the [Elements of UML Style](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/)  useful for answering this sort of question.